# EF 6 "Translate" method equivalent in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have the following statement from EF 6, which reads from a `DbDataReader` using an EF context and outputs the result in the specified type T (`GetProducts_Result`):

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.Translate<GetProducts_Result>(reader);
```

Is there any equivalent for this in EF Core?

Comment: FromSql is the closest equivalent

Comment: Not useful, but thanks.

Comment: No, luckily with each version EF gradually moves further into abstracting the data layer. Also, EF core is a complete rebuild. No `ObjectContext` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is no equivalent for this method in EF Core, I wrote the following static method in the class defining the `GetProducts_Result` type, which is in charge of returning a `List` of `GetProducts_Result` from the `DbDataReader`:

```
public static List<GetProducts_Result> CreateFromReader(DbDataReader reader)
{
    List<GetProducts_Result> result = new List<GetProducts_Result>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        result.Add(new GetProducts_Result
        {
            Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")),
            Brand = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Brand")),
            ... // read remaining fields
        }

    return result;
}
```

Probably not the best approach, but I was in the need of migrating the initial EF 6 code to EF Core and this works pretty well.